# Django migrations - change model from Int to CharField and pre-populate from choice option

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

In a model, I have an `IntegerField` that is mapped to a `CHOICES` tuple.  The requirements for that field have changed to the point that updating the options in that tuple will require too frequent maintenance, so I've decided to alter it to a `CharField`

Is there a way I can do this inside the migrations, or would it be better to create a new column, update with the appropriate value and delete old column?

Answer (score 2):

You've changed your Schema so you'll definitely need a Schema migration and Django will do that for you, with the `makemigrations` command.

But since you're also changing the type of a column, in which is filled with integers and now should be cast to characters, Django won't do that automatically for you and you need to write [Data migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#data-migrations).

In my experience, it's better to generate multiple migrations; one that creates a new CharField and then write to this new column via RunPython. Then, run a second migration that removes the original IntegerField and renames the new CharField column as your original column. (I guess it's what you yourself suggested)

Answer (score 0):

To make it more clear, you need 3 migrations.

1. for Schema migration - adding a new field.
2. for Data migration - You can use the link below which is perfect example for data migration.
3. for Schema migration - deleting the old field.

Here is the example I've followed before doing my first data migrations.

[Data Migration Example](https://realpython.com/blog/python/data-migrations/)